# Accessing an item that's inside of a list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list

```
public static List<Courses> course = new List<Courses>();
```

And Courses looks like this,

```
 class Courses
{
    public string courseName { get; set; }
    public List<Faculty> faculty { get; set; }
    public List<Student> student { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {  
        return courseName + ", which features " + faculty.Count + ", faculty member(s) and " + student.Count + " student(s).";
    }
}
```

Im trying to access the List faculty inside of of the list course so I can traverse and print the contents of it. How would I go about doing this in C#?

Below is how im trying to access it in another class.

```
 //print stuff
        int courseCounter = 0, studentCounter = 0, facultyCounter = 0;
        //object[] o = course.ToArray()
        foreach(object o in course)
        {
            courseCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine("Course #" + courseCounter + " is " + o.ToString());

            foreach(object f in HOW WOULD I ACCESS IT HERE)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: You have a list of courses. Which one are you interested in? The first? Do you want to enumerate them?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific... you seem to know how to use `for` or `foreach` to traverse the main collection, the same principle applies.

Comment: You are already accessing it when you say *faculty.Count*. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: Why would I access it in the class courses, that is just defining the list. Im trying to access it in a different class.

Comment: First loop through courses list, then through faculty list, where you call toString you going to override for faculty class.. May be better way exists..

Comment: you mean `o.faculty` ?

Comment: `faculty` is public, so you can iterate it as you iterate the courses `foreach (var f in o.faculty) { ... }`

Comment: `foreach(object o` isn't very useful. You won't be able to access the specific properties of the class that way. Either use the implicit type `var` like this `foreach(var o` or provide the specific type like this `foreach(Course c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't use `object` as your iteration variable type. You won't be able to access any class specific members... and its just weird.

Use the class type:

```
foreach (Course course in courses)
```

or for places that like `var` (this is type *inference*, `var` gets replaced by `Course` under the hood because that is the generic type argument of `courses`. In different contexts it will choose the type differently... something to learn about separately)

```
foreach (var course in courses)
```

Once you have that, the inner loop is very simple, just access `Faculty` (its already `public`)

```
foreach(Faculty f in course.Faculty)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Ive haven't done too much with lists and though a generic type would suffice.

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't *ever* be using `object` as a variable type. Especially as a student. (simple semaphores excluded)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is this line:

```
foreach(object o in course)
```

The loop variable `o` is actually a `Course`, but since it is of type `Object` it does not know about its properties unless you cast it.

If you change the loop variable to a `Course` then you can access the properties.

```
foreach(Courses c in course)
{
    courseCounter++;
    Console.WriteLine("Course #" + courseCounter + " is " + c.ToString());

    foreach(Faculty f in c.faculty)
    {

    }

    foreach(Student s in c.student)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: or  you can use `var`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the class you've created `public` to access it's internal fields and variables.

```
public class Courses
{
    //Properties (Begin property with a capital)
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public List<Faculty> Faculties { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {  
        return courseName + ", which features " + faculty.Count + ", faculty member(s) and " + student.Count + " student(s).";
    }
}
```

Now if you create some courses and put them in your list you can access them like this:

```
//Create a new course or as many as you wish and fill the model class with data.
Course mathCourse = new Course()
{
    CourseName = "Math",
    Faculties = new List<Faculty>(),
    Students = new List<Student>()
;
mathCourse.Faculties.Add(new Faculty("Faculty for math Alpha"));
mathCourse.Faculties.Add(new Faculty("Faculty for math Beta"));
mathcourse.Students.Add(new Student("Ben"));

//create as many different courses as you want and at them to your list you've created.
course.Add(mathCourse);

//you can now reach the faculty in the course like this
//We select with [0] the first course in the courseList, then we select the first faculty of the course with [0] and select its property 'name'.
//This goes for any property as long the class Faculty is public and its property is too.
string facultyName = course[0].Faculties[0].Name;

//>> facultyName => Faculty for math Alpha
```

Maybe this documentation can help you further:
[Microsoft on properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)
[MSDN on collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ybcx56wz%28v=vs.120%29#Implementieren%20einer%20Auflistung%20von%20Schl%C3%BCssel/Wert-Paaren)

I hope that helped!

**EDIT**
I took too long writing this and missed your edit that you'd like a foreach-loop. See other answers for that. :)